# Casting SelectedItem of WPF Combobox to Color causes exception

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, casting, selecteditem

I have a combobox databound to the available system colors. When the user selects a color the following code is fired:

```
private void cboFontColour_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Color colour = (Color)(cboFontColour.SelectedItem);
}
```

This throws a Casting Exception with the following message: "Specified cast is not valid." When I hover over cboFontColour.SelectedItem in the debugger, it is always a Color object.

I do not understand why the system seemingly cannot cast from Color to Color, any help would be much obliged.

Comment: Is it the same namespace? That is, is one of them Something.Color and the other SomethingElse.Etc.Color?

Comment: Yes, they're all in the same namespace. Both are System.Windows.Media.Color

Comment: Could you give us the XAML that you use to create the ComboBox?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh finally solved it. What the function actually returned was a DependancyProperty instead of a Color. Not sure how I missed it for so long

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `is` and `as` instead of direct type conversion.
Additionally make sure that Color is actually the same type you see in the Debugger.

Comment: I tried that, but I get a compile error:

Error 8 The as operator must be used with a reference type or nullable type ('System.Windows.Media.Color' is a non-nullable value type)

Comment: @Nick Udell, you can do `Color? colour = cboFontColour.SelectedItem as Color?;`, and then check if it's null. Read more on `is` and `as` and so on on other, complete, threads about it.

Comment: Just curious: then how do you get the Color value if the value is not a Color?!

Answer (score 0):

How did you set up the binding to the available system colors? If you are using the static properties of the `SystemColors` class then note that despite the name of the class, not all of these entries are Color objects (but SolidColorBrushes and ResourceKeys too). You can always do an

```
    MessageBox.Show(cboFontColour.SelectedItem.GetType().ToString());
    // or
    MessageBox.Show(cboFontColour.SelectedValue.GetType().ToString());
```

to check the type.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem, and none of the suggestions from this question worked.  I kept getting exceptions when trying to cast as (Color), and the code wouldn't even compile if I tried using 'Color?' or 'as'.  Ended up coming up with the following workaround.  It's not ideal, because I now have to create a new object, but at least it works:

```
string colorName = _comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString();
Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(colorName);
```